# How Does This Website Block Pinch-to-Zoom on iPad?

Tags: ipad, html, mobile, zooming, responsive-design

I visited [mobile-apps-news](http://www.mobile-apps-news.com/) on an iPad and noticed there's no way I can pinch-to-zoom, it's using a responsive layout - but I'm very curious to how they've blocked pinch zooming under iOS. It's definitely not Javascript.

Anyone know how they've done this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a mobile safari web-kit property. The meta tag named `view port` has the ability to do so. It defines many parameter in which  `user-scalable = no` value of `Content` parameter is what you are looking for. It prevents user from scaling the page just by adding a property to the meta tag. You can use the same tag to specify your initial scale and maximum zoom level. `<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable = no">`. For more information, have a look at the [safari developer guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).

Comment: wekcome dude. . Glad it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add it with the right syntax, defining the content as well:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```